# validates_acceptance_of not working for a checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying various options for the past three hours to make a "terms and conditions" checkbox working

Here is my code 
/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #validates :terms, acceptance: { accept: true } , :on => :create
  validates_acceptance_of :terms, :allow_nil => false,  :accept => true, :on => :create
end
```

this is what I am always getting
[image]

html looks like this 
[image]

I added this to allow params

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  # for allowing terms in signup 
  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:terms])
  end

end
```

[image]
'rails', '4.2.8'

Comment: Could you log `devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:terms])`, see what is its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `1` as a checkbox value. It's a default for the validator. So all you need is to get rid of `:accept => true` option.
The `true` one is used only in case of validating boolean database field. As I understand you don't have such a column in users table and only want to referer to the HTML checkbox.